# How to get dropdown option value using dropdown option in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I'm developing a automation that needs to access the first (and only one) dropdown value. I want to get this "Unavailable date" value to do a validation in the future. This is the HTML:

```
<div class = "content-box-wrapper">
    <fieldset>
        <li>
            <label>Select a time</label>
    
            <div>
                <select name = "idAgenda" id="hourSelected">
                    <option value>Unavailable date</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </li>
    </fieldset>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it using getText() method:

```
WebElement disponibilidade = chrome.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"hourSelected\"]"));
String text1 = disponibilidade.getText();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
Select hours = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("hoursSelected")));


hours.selectByIndex(1);
hours.selectByVisibleText("Unavailable date");
hours.selectByValue("Unavailable date")
```

Since it's in a Select tag you can use the following import and select by index or value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the below `xPath` to get the selected value of drop-down.

```
//select[@id='hourSelected']/option
```

In case, if drop-down is having multiple values then if it have `selected` tag for selected value. Please write `xPath` as below,

**`HTML`**

```
<option value="">Unavailable date1</option>
<option selected="" value="">Unavailable date2</option>
<option value="">Unavailable date3</option>
```

**`xPath`**

```
//select[@id='hourSelected']/option[@selected]
```